# Get user email from loginviewcontroller and show in revealview's label

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I have almost built an app but I want to show the email address of current user in the reveal view or side view's label.  The reveal view is a tableviewcontroller and the loginview is a simple viewcontroller.

I used following code in login view controller:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let target = segue.destinationViewController as? backTableVC {
           target.labelname = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("currentuser")
        }
    }
```

And the following code in the reveal view controller:

```
var labelname:String? {
    didSet {
    emailLabel!.text = labelname
    }
}
 @IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        emailLabel.text = labelname
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

emailLabel.text = labelname     
}
```

I put the breakpoint at the last line of this code but I get nil as  lablename's value and it also does not change value in the label of reveal view's label.

The code for login view controller is as

```
import UIKit
```

class LoginViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var userPasswordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var userEmailTextField: UITextField!
var currentuseremail:String?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.userEmailTextField.delegate = self
    self.userPasswordTextField.delegate = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
func textFieldShouldReturn(userText: UITextField) -> Bool {
    userText.resignFirstResponder()
    return true;
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
var userEmail:String?
var userPassword:String?
@IBAction func loginButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (userEmailTextField.text! != "")
    {
        userEmail = userEmailTextField.text}
    else {
        alert("Please Enter Your email")
    }
    if (userPasswordTextField != ""){
        userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text}
    else {
        alert("Please Enter Password")
    }
    let userEmailStored = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userEmail")
    let userPasswordStored = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userPassword")

    if(userEmailStored == userEmail) {
        if(userPasswordStored == userPassword) {
            // Login is Successfull
            currentuseremail = userEmail
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(currentuseremail, forKey: "currentuser")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIN")

            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    else {
        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Email or Password doesn't match", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        myAlert.addAction(okAction)
        self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
func alert(message:String) {
    let myalert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    myalert.addAction(action)
    self.presentViewController(myalert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let target = segue.destinationViewController as? backTableVC {
       target.labelname = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("currentuser")
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Alright so what it looks like is userEmailStored is not really what you think it is.

So try printing out userEmailStored

```
let userEmailStored = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userEmail")
print(userEmailStored)
```

then print out user Email

```
print(userEmail)
```

According to what I can see, userEmailStored will always be nil, because there is no `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setString("userEmail")` or whatever the exact method is.

What I mean is, before you can access a value saved with the string "userEmail", you must save something to "userEmail". I don't see that happening, therefore anytime you access `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userEmail")` it will return "" or nil

Comment: I am getting the labelname value from other view controller through segue code

Comment: Show it, I can provide more help from there.

Comment: override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let target = segue.destinationViewController as? backTableVC {
           target.labelname = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("currentuser")
        }
    }

Comment: I provided an edit for your code so now it is more readable, give me a moment to read over what you were actually trying to say.

Comment: Yea, that works too! Just make sure to do it correctly.

Comment: Looking through it now, gimme a few

Comment: I only want user email from login view controller as if I do not use ns user defaults then the nil is same.The user email stored is stored in the ns user defaults thats why it allows the user to login otherwise it will not allow the user to login.I have saved the value of useremail in signup controller.Thats why I am comparing the value the user provided to match the value saved before